# In javascript is it possible to get the reference to global var name (window,...) from another variable known to be in global?

Tags: javascript

let's suppose user is not in known environment browser, node, but in an unknown javascript platform, is it possible for him
to deduct from a variable g in global, the name of that global within a local function?

something like this:

```
function test() {
    globalName = getGlobalFrom("g");
}
```

Comment: What is the real problem that you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd need the name, but you can get the reference by just checking for whichever exists:

```
const globalRef = global || globalThis || self || window;
```

If you really want the name as a string for some reason, you can then do `globalRef.toString()` and it'll return something like `"[object Window]"` or `"[object global]"` or similar.